# Who are the parents of Umm al Baneen?

Tags: history, ali

Who are the parents of [Umm al Baneen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umm_ul-Banin) (Fatima al Kalabiya), the wife of [Ali Ibn Abi Talib](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ali) and mother of Abbas and three other sons?

I couldn't find any information about her parents, except that her fathers name is Huzam ibn Khalid.

Only mentioning names is not enough, of course. I'd like to know who her father (and mother) was. Was he a companion of the Prophet or of Ali Ibn Abi Talib? When did he live? How did he die?

Answer (score 3):

```
               In the name of Allah the most compassionate the most merciful
```

First of all, it can be helpful for you to be aware that:

> After the martyrdom of Hazrat Fatimah-a-Zahra, as the wife of Imam Ali
>   (a.s.), Imam Ali sent his brother (Aqil ibn Abi Talib who was familiar
>   with to Arab Ensaab (genealogy)) and asked him to find him a wife from
>   a valiant and brave family till …)

Aqil (a.s.) chose Um-al-Banin-Kalabiah for Imam Ali, that her tribe and family was incomparable and unexampled in bravery. In truth, Bani-Kalab were proverbial and famous for their bravery between Arabs. Moreover it is narrated that her mother was Thomamah as a true-hearted and virtuous (piety) woman, therefore understandably it can be inferred that both of her parents would be considered as two positive persons who were at the way or followers or Sahabah of the Prophet (and Imam Ali as you asked), otherwise logically Imam Ali wouldn’t choose them.  For more info. as helpful info. regarding what you need, I assume the following book would be related for you. مروج الذهب، المسعودي، ج۳، ص۶۳./ العقد الفرید، احمد بن عبد ربه، ج۵، ص۱۳۴.

In the meantime, as a helpful matter regarding "if her father was from Sahalba"  @ Medi added in his comment:

> her father (May Allah be pleased with him) is among the sahaba this is
>   quoted in al isaabah from ibn Hajar al 'asqalani! – Medi Saif

---

In regard to the Nasab (descent) of Um-al-Banin (s.a.) (acnd actually the descent of his father, Hazam ibn Khalid), you’d better see the following issue which God willing would be constructive and helpful for you about her father and mother.

At the initial step, in regard to her father, she was Fatimah, the daughter of:

> حزام بن خالد بن ربيعه بن وحيد بن كعب بن عامر بن كلاب بن ربيعة بن عامر
>   بن صعصعة بن معاوية بن بكر بن هوازن

---

And her mother was from the family of:

> سهل بن عامر بن مالك بن جعفر بن كلاب
>
> (Sahl-ibn-Amer-ibn-Malik-ibn-Jafar-ibn-Klab)

And her Jaddah or ancestress include:

> First ancestress:
>
> جده اول : عمره دخت (بنت) طفيل بن مالك احزام بن جعفر كلاب .
>
> 2th:
>
> كبته دخت (بنت) عروة الرحال فرزند جعفر بن كلاب
>
> 3th:   ام خشف دخت (بنت) ابى معاوية فارس هزار بن عبادة بن عقيل بن كلاب
>
> 4th:    فاطمه دخت (بنت) جعفر بن كلاب
>
> 5th:   عاتكه دخت (بنت) عبدالشمس بن عبد مناف بن قصى ، جده حضرت رسول صلى
>   الله عليه و آله
>
> 6th:
>
> آمنه دخت (بنت) وهب بن عمير بن نصر بن قعين بن حرث بن ثلعبه بن ذودان بن
>   اسد بن خزيمه
>
> 7th:   دخت (بنت) جحدر بن ضبيعه اغر بن قيس بن ثلعبية بن عكاية بن صعب بن
>   على بن بكر بن وائل بن ربيعه بن نزار
>
> جد حضرت رسول خدا صلى الله عليه و آله
>
> 8th:    دخت (بنت) ملك بن قيس بن ثعلبه
>
> 9th:
>
> دخت (بنت) الراءسين : خشين بن ابى عصم بن سمح بن فزاره
>
> 10th:
>
> دخت (بنت) عمر بن صرمة بن عوف بن سعد بن ذبيان بن بغيض بن ريث بن غطفان .

---

**Reference:**

- [wikifeqh.ir](http://wikifeqh.ir/%D8%A7%D9%85%E2%80%8C%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A8%D9%86%DB%8C%D9%86#foot2)
- [www.aviny.com](http://www.aviny.com/occasion/Ahlebeit/Bastegan/Ommolbanin/83/Zendeginameh.aspx)
- [www.akhlagh.net](http://www.akhlagh.net/lib/15/1/20/content-7.html)

Comment: Just to support your answer Arabic Wikipedia says the same: father: Hazem ibn Khalid ibn Rabi'a ibn 'Amir ibn Sa'sa'h al Kilaby, mother: Thamamah bint sahl ibn 'Amir!

Comment: Uh-huh, Well done mate. Your supporting would be helpful as you presented. God Bless You.

Comment: Finally an addition her father (May Allah be pleased with him) is among the sahaba this is quoted in al isaabah from ibn Hajar al 'asqalani!

Comment: Indeed? oops, it can be a great support for the questioner and likewise the response. So, I'd add it to the answer (as what you pointed out).

Comment: Thank you for your very good answer. I'm still surprised that there is so little to tell about her father. Not a single story in which he is included. Not even his job. Nothing, except that he appears on a list of sahaba (on which also doubtful persons are listed)

Comment: Firstly your welcome. Secondly you are right to some extent. Thirdly we should notice that "actually, commonly, there are more info. regarding the famous persons" and usually unfortunately there is less info. regarding less-famous persons as a rule". (although lack of extensive info doesn't mean that some person is not a great). Fourthly and actually finally according to available evidences apparently he was a good person that ... / Your curiosity is interesting. I am at your service if you have more question (based on my limited info.)/  Good luck mate.

Comment: Well as she was born as it seems in year 5 a.H. it's more likely that both of her parents saw the Messenger of Allah (peace be upon him) http://www.alkafeel.net/forums/archive/index.php/t-27957.html it was narrated that she her father was expecting a girl who will marry a honorable Man as he saw something like this in a dream during his travel, when he came back his wife gave life to a girl whom was named Fatimah and given the kinyah Um Al-Banyn. The tribe of Bani Kliab was well known for their valor and heroism in Jahilya!

Comment: Uh-huh, I haven't heard that. As already mentioned, I didn't find much info. either. ُSince seemingly there is not much information about him. And God knows best. و من الله توفیق